# Are character names unique in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

From the beta, I have heard that characters of the same name can be created as long as they do not belong to the same account. **Is this true, and will it extend to the final release?**

I'm also rather curious as to how the game deals with conflicts. For example, what if two characters of the same name join one game? In Diablo 2 this would have been quite confusing. I assume it has something to do with battle tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Battle tags are unique, but character names are not necessarily. Remember, the battle tag includes the number, so two people can choose the "same" battle tag but will still be differentiated based on the number afterwards.

Most of the in-game interactions are done via battle tag, not character name. When someone chats, his battle tag (without the numbers) is displayed instead of his character name. Similarly, people's battle tags are shown under their character portraits rather than their character name.

It may get confusing if two people with the same base battle tag join the game.

Comment: Great, thanks! If you don't mind my asking, where does the character name come into play if battle tags are basically more important? E.g. how would D2's party window translate?

Comment: @JamieSchembri It seems that character names are now *purely* for flavor. They don't play any mechanical role at all.

Comment: @StrixVaria Are they *purely* for flavour? Do they not serve the purpose of differentiating multiple characters held by someone with the same BattleTag?

Comment: The names aren't even unique on your own account. I had two barbarians with the exact same name.

Answer (score -2):

@StrixVaria not sure if any of that info is correct, im coming up with unique names that may be popular and the game just released so its too soon to tell. But i do know in the beta your characters name showed up in game and next to your flag. Maybe for everyone else they see your battletag, but im pretty sure its the character name, because i know my character name showed up for me.

I cant remember if there was dialog that involved non voice acting but if there is im sure your name will pop up there too.